# Calculating the distance on a parallel plane to the normal vector

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, distance, rotational-matrices, matrix-transform

My mathematics (and matlab) is just not up to this and so I humbly ask for your help:

I have a model of flow through a annulus. I want to get the radius of the peak flow point and the radius of the annulus to the centreline.

So, I have 3 points, ABC, in a 3D model whose co-ordinates we know but not aligned to xyz. I want AB to be two points on a plane and point A to be the origin (centre of the annulus). Point C is on a plane parallel to the previous plane (the peak flow point). I would like to know how to calculate the distance between C on its plane to the normal vector of the AB plane that goes through the point A.

Here are pics of the model:
[Flow through an annulus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOHwB.jpg)
[Points in the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4RuY.jpg)

Now I've had a friend who's cleverer than I come up with a matlab code to translate and rotate the model and then calculate the magnitudes of AB and AnormC. However, it's not working as it puts C at a greater radius than B. I also realise there is more than one way to solve this problem.

The code is below. Any thoughts where we've gone wrong? Or maybe is there a better way to do this? I thought of vectors but my scribblings amount to nought.

Thank you.

Toby

```
%Origin
O = [0 0 0]';           Ox = [O' 1]';
%Vector co-ordinates of 1 (A - Origin centreline), ...
% 2 (B - Radius of artery), and 3 (C - Radius of Peak Velocity)
A = [13.3856 -60.0377 15.8443]';           Ax = [A' 1]';
B = [26.9486 -51.0653 20.9265]';           Bx = [B' 1]';
C = [16.2240 -92.5594 40.8687]';           Cx = [C' 1]';
%Find the new i unit vector in the old co-ords (the unit vector along the new x axis)
AB = B - A;
magAB = sqrt(sum(AB.^2));
new_i=AB./magAB;
%Calculate the angle to rotate through Z when transforming
thetaZ = atan(new_i(2)/new_i(1));
%Hence, define the translation matrix (to move the origin to A) and ...
% the rotation matrixes (to align the new x axis with AB and new_i)
T = [1 0 0 -A(1) ; 0 1 0  -A(2) ; 0 0 1 -A(3) ; 0 0 0 1];
Rz = [cos(thetaZ) sin(thetaZ) 0 0 ; -sin(thetaZ) cos(thetaZ) 0 0 ; 0 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 1];
Transform = Rz * T;
%transform Cx to the new co-ordinates by translation and rotation in Z
A_dash = round(Transform * Ax,10);
B_dash = round(Transform * Bx,10);
C_dash = round(Transform * Cx,10);
new_i_t = round(Transform * [new_i' 1]',4); new_i_t = new_i_t(1:3);
new_O = round(Transform * Ox,4); new_O = new_O(1:3);
A_dash = A_dash(1:3); B_dash = B_dash(1:3); C_dash = C_dash(1:3);
%Perform a final rotation in Y
thetaY = atan(B_dash(3)/B_dash(1));
Ry = [cos(thetaY) 0 sin(thetaY) ; 0 1 0 ; -sin(thetaY) 0 cos(thetaY)];
B_dash = Ry * B_dash;
C_dash = Ry * C_dash;
%Taking point C onto the plane of AB
C_dashflat = C_dash.*[1 1 0]';
%Find Radius of Peak Flow 
Radius_Peak_Flow = sqrt(sum(C_dashflat.^2));
%Find Radius of Artery  
Radius_Artery = magAB;
%Ratio (between 0 -1)
Ratio = Radius_Peak_Flow/Radius_Artery
```

Comment: You must define a few more constraints to solve the problem as you described. You said "I want AB to be two points on a plane and point A to be the origin". 2 points define infinitely many planes, you would need at some more information to define what is this plane. Once you define it, you can calculate the distance of this plane to C.

Comment: Thank you Thales. A bolt from from the blue hit me yesterday and I remembered the same thing that 3 points are needed to describe a plane. I'll post the script if it works; might help someone else in future. Toby